# Passing computed parameters to middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-middleware

I would like to pass a computed value into my middleware through my web.php routes file.  I have this model configuration:

Planet hasMany Countries

Country hasMany Cities

City hasMany Buildings

In all of my routes I need to build a menu that helps navigate between planets.  So, no matter what I'm doing I need to be able to access the planet->id.  Right now, in my middleware I have a long series of if/elseif checking to see which parameters exist in the URL:

```
if (isset($parameters['planet'])) 
    $planetId = $parameters['planet']->id;
else if (isset($parameters['country'])) 
    $planetId = $parameters['country']->planet->id;
else if (isset($parameters['building'])) 
    $planetId = $parameters['building']->country->planet->id;
```

Obviously this gets very unwieldy very quickly and I feel like there should be a better way to pass the planetId into the middleware but I cannot find any way to gracefully do that...

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're better off just adding "planet_id" to all of your models that use their planet reference frequently.

Writing logic with a bunch of nested relationship referencing can really take a toll on the speed of your application. Writing the extra data which seems counter intuitive at first, will actually really help. You want to prioritize the speed of your SELECT queries over the size of your database where you can reasonably. Your SELECT queries will be the majority of your applications database usage. In our modern day having a few extra bytes isn't that big of a deal and it would serve a huge purpose here.

- Add planet_id to your countries and buildings migration table.
- Add relationship method "planet" to your country and building model class.

Then you can easily do something like:

```
function getPlanetFromRequest($request)
{
    $parameters = $request->all();
    $planetParameterNames = ['building', 'country', 'planet'];

    foreach ($planetParameterNames as $planetParameterName) {
        if (isset($parameters[$planetParameterName])) {
            $model = $parameters[$planetParameterName];

            // if the model is a planet, just return its self.
            if ($model instanceof Planet) {
                return $model;
            }

            // $model would be country or building.
            return $model->planet;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

If you only need the planets id, save yourself a query and just reference the models planet_id rather than referencing its planet and then grabbing the id.

```
$country->planet_id; // NOT $country->planet->id;
```